# Why do I need to specify the argument list for a class template in a function?

Tags: c++, templates

So I have this really simple code that I'm using to get the hang on templates

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

template <typename T, typename U, typename V>
class Foo{

private:
    T x;
    U y;
    V z;

public:
    Foo(T a, U b, V c){
        this->x = a;
        this->y = b;
        this->z = c;
    }

    friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, const Foo &foo);
};

ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, const Foo &foo){

    os << foo->x << ", " << foo->y << ", " << foo->z;
    return os;

}
```

But it tells me that I need to specify what types (the Foo object that I'm using for overloading the operator) it is using.

Wouldn't that defeat the purpose of templates by having to duplicate code for Foo objects with different Types?

Comment: Why don't you make `operator<<` a template as well?

Comment: `this` is a pointer, you can't write `this.x`, instead write `this->x`.

Comment: Or use initializer lists like `Foo(T a, U b, V c) : x(a), y(b), z(c) { }`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to make `operator<<` a template as well, so it can match to an appropriate template instantiation for `Foo`:

```
template<typename A, typename B, typename C>
ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, const Foo<A, B, C> &foo){
    os << foo.x << ", " << foo.y << ", " << foo.z; // Changed -> to ., since foo is a reference, not pointer
    return os;
}
```

Similarly, the `friend` declaration within the class should be a template, e.g.

```
template<typename A, typename B, typename C>
friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, const Foo<A, B, C>& foo);
```

A somewhat nicer solution might be to define the `friend` function entirely within the class, removing the need for explicit `template`ing:

```
template <typename T, typename U, typename V>
class Foo{
    // Rest of class here

    // No need for template keyword, extra <>, new typenames, etc.
    friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, const Foo<T, U, V>& foo) {
        os << foo.x << ", " << foo.y << ", " << foo.z;
        return os;
    }
};
```

Comment: You’ll need to make the friend declaration a template, too. Currently the code won’t compile.

Comment: Also since `foo` isn't a pointer, those should be `foo.x` instead of `foo->x`, etc.

Comment: @NathanPierson: Ah, yes, missed the mistake in the OP. Fixed now.

Comment: Adding to @KonradRudolph's comment, you'll also want the function template declaration visible before the class template definition. Or it may be much easier just to define the friend inside the class (and in that case it can be a non-template). See https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/templates#template-friends

Comment: @max66 See aschepler’s comment: it doesn’t *have* to be a template, but then it *must* be declared inside the class — and you cannot do this for the output stream operator, since, if declared inside the class, its first argument needs to be `Foo` (unless, that is, you also *define* the friend function inside the class template; it’s weird).

Comment: @aschepler: Excellent. That same link provides a "cleaner way" that "inherits" the same template parameters as `Foo` itself possesses. Though it adds other pre-declaration nonsense, so probably simpler to just use new template.

Answer (score 3):

There are at least three mistakes that I can see:

1. The constructor is trying to access `this.x` (etc.). But `this` is a *pointer*. Furthermore, you should use an [initialiser list](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constructor), not assignment, in the constructor.
2. Your `operator <<` is attempting to use a non-existent class `Foo`. You need to convert your function into a *function template* which uses the *class template* `Foo<T, U, V>`. Likewise, your `friend` function declaration needs to be a function template declaration.
3. Inside `operator <<`, `foo` isn’t a pointer, it’s a value object – use `.` instead of `->` to access members.

Taken together:

```
#include <iostream>

template <typename T, typename U, typename V>
class Foo{
private:
    T x;
    U y;
    V z;

public:
    Foo(T x, U y, V z) : x(x), y(y), z(y) {}

    template <typename T1, typename U1, typename V1>
    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, Foo<T1, U1, V1> const& foo);
};

template <typename T, typename U, typename V>
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, Foo<T, U, V> const& foo) {
    return os << foo.x << ", " << foo.y << ", " << foo.z;
}
```